# jQuery .load() not working properly

Tags: jquery

Here's the page in question:

http://www.lukaspleva.com/MoneyThink/NationalAdmin.php

If you go to that page, you'll see that you can remove chapters from the system just by clicking the red cross button next to each row. As you do that, the chapter counter at the top automatically updates.

Problem arises when you add a new chapter to the mix via the section at the top. The new section gets added and the counter updates, but the delete button stops working.

Looking at what's happening with the code, it seems like the .load() function is creating an additional form="update_existing_chapters" WITHIN  the form id="update_existing_chapters" that's already on the page.

Basically, instead of just refreshing the div or the form, it creates a duplicate copy within it, which breaks the code.

The relevant piece of code is:

```
$('form#update_existing_chapters')
    .load('NationalAdmin.php form#update_existing_chapters');
```

Any idea why it's creating a duplicate element/section rather than just refreshing the current one?

***UPDATE #1***

I now realize I have to use .on() to preserve the delete event for the buttons. I tried the following code, but that actually breaks the AJAX completely. Any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
               $('#current_chapters').on('click', '.delete-chapter', function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "http://www.lukaspleva.com/MoneyThink/CreateNewChapter.php",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: $('#create_new_chapter').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){ alert(msg); $('#current_chapters').load('NationalAdmin.php #current_chapters'); } 
                    });
            return false;
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reloading list, your events for delete buttons resets. You must use parent DOM element which stay untouched.

```
$('#current_chapters_container').on('click', '.delete-chapter', function(){
    alert('delete');
});
```

**Update**
We can see several problems:

- load function is used for loading part of content, but here we
  receive full page (with html, body and etc)
- after inserting content we lose delete events (`on` is good alternative
  for `live`)
- You replace form content with another form, that's why you have two forms.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain that a little bit more?

Comment: I answer on problem with delete buttons. When you load data from server and replace content, all attached events with `$(".delete-chapter")` removes. Just replace my alert with your code (where you use confirm).

Comment: Stop, as I can see in console you totally loading page with ajax, it is wrong logic.

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't be using AJAX at all?

Comment: @Lukas Pleva No, you should use it, but load only list from server, no need in full page.

Comment: Right, so that's what I am TRYING to do; I know I shouldn't be loading the full page. Are you saying it shouldn't be .load('NationalAdmin.php form#update_existing_chapters')? I thought that meant I was just reloading the form that has the list, not the full page.

Comment: @Lukas Pleva `load()` - Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. (http://api.jquery.com/load/) Open console, I use firebug and you will see ajax requests, you load full page.

Comment: Thanks for all your help thus far! I realize I have to use .on() to make the code work. I tried to incorporate it into my existing code (posted in my original question, under "Update #1", but that actually breaks the code completely. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: @Lukas Pleva I was taking about delete, but you replace create function, of course, it can't work. `on` selector works like `find`, it looking for DOM nodes in current selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form#update_existing_chapters')
    .empty()
    .load('NationalAdmin.php form#update_existing_chapters');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but still running into the problem I pointed out above :(